# Send push notification using php and ionic alpha push notification

Tags: php, android, ionic-framework

I have follow the all steps to built simple app in ionic framework from [here](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-sending-push).And I am using php code for server side to call the ionic [API for push notification](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-sending-push). I have Used the following code but i am not getting notification in my app , Please suggest the solution.

```
    <?php
    $androidAppId = "e2c77770";
    $data = array(
      "tokens" => "APA91bF2YePDKxE6K6vZYs2KQ27Z4mdehJg-EaZaPy10w-RHN5RUgC_P6Uie24Qu_M28j9bfZcbU6pu8Awofa8h2G5j9jABnebrVIUgKM5JcZPEJHYVW2NINirAm7VnSqGOrqm4YicAoI9Xiw5zkgTx4edqXIANLEhvqsqSCeq-_gAuzZB8wvrQ",
      "notification" => "Hello World!"
    );
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init('https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-Ionic-Application-Id: '.$androidAppId,
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never dealt with ionic but according to the python example given in http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-sending-push you should add Authorization header to the request.

```
private_key = YOUR_PRIVATE_API_KEY
b64 = base64.encodestring('%s:' % private_key).replace('\n', '')
#I didn't get why they used colon while encoding the api key??
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % b64)
```

PHP implementation of that python snippet would be like that;

```
<?php
$yourApiSecret = "YOUR API SECRET";
$androidAppId = "e2c77770";
$data = array(
  "tokens" => "APA91bF2YePDKxE6K6vZYs2KQ27Z4mdehJg-EaZaPy10w-RHN5RUgC_P6Uie24Qu_M28j9bfZcbU6pu8Awofa8h2G5j9jABnebrVIUgKM5JcZPEJHYVW2NINirAm7VnSqGOrqm4YicAoI9Xiw5zkgTx4edqXIANLEhvqsqSCeq-_gAuzZB8wvrQ",
  "notification" => "Hello World!"
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/push');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Ionic-Application-Id: '.$androidAppId,
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($yourApiSecret)
    )
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Also output of the result may tell you a lot about the status of push notification you want to send.

Comment: Thank you for your response ,, I have tried this but getting response false on screen...

Comment: Have you tried with a false api secret? When I run the code above this is the response, `{"result":"error","message":"Unable to Authenticate"}` you should be getting something similar.

Comment: yes I have tried with multiple options , but i am not getting solution.

Comment: I think you have to share dump of $result and curl_error($ch)

Answer (score 2):

I have created a complete library that allows you to consume the *Ionic Cloud API* for sending push notifications (*normal and scheduled*), get a paginated list of sending push notifications, get notifications messages, get information of registered devices, remove registered devices by token, etc.

This library requires `PHP 5.1+` and `cURL`.

---

#### Installation:

```
composer require tomloprod/ionic-push-php
```

---

#### Sending a notification:

```
use Tomloprod\IonicApi\Push;

$ionicPushApi = new Push($ionicProfile, $ionicAPIToken);

// Configuration of the notification
$notificationConfig = [
    'title' => 'Your notification title',
    'message' => 'Your notification message. Bla, bla, bla, bla.'
];

// [OPTIONAL] You can also pass custom data to the notification. Default => []
$payload = [ 
    'myCustomField' => 'This is the content of my customField',
    'anotherCustomField' => 'More custom content'
];

// [OPTIONAL] And define, if you need it, a silent notification. Default => false
$silent = true;

// [OPTIONAL] Or/and even a scheduled notification for an indicated datetime. Default => ''
$scheduled = '2016-12-10 10:30:10';

// [OPTIONAL] Filename of audio file to play when a notification is received. Setting this to default will use the default device notification sound. Default => 'default'
$sound = 'default';

// Configure notification:
$ionicPushApi->notifications->setConfig($notificationConfig, $payload, $silent, $scheduled, $sound);

// Send notification to all registered devices:
$ionicPushApi->notifications->sendNotificationToAll();

// or send notification to some devices:
$ionicPushApi->notifications->sendNotification([$desiredToken1, $desiredToken2, $desiredToken3]);
```

---

You can read more about this library here: https://github.com/tomloprod/ionic-push-php